# Tizen Emulator not running on mac

Tags: memory, mobile, shared-memory, tizen, tizen-emulator

I am facing problem while creating and launching Tizen Emulator.I am getting following error
"Cannot launch this VM.Shared memory is not enough."

[image]

Regards

Comment: Can you please give some details on your system configuration? Host OS? GPU ? CPU ?

Comment: Same problem. Host is OS X 10.8.3, Core i5, 4Gb RAM, Intel HD Graphics 3000.
Error in logs indicate video initialization issue:

    [info:qemu:maru_vga]shared memory key: 26102, vga ram_size : 16777216
    [err:qemu:maru_vga]shmget failed
    maru_vga: : Cannot allocate memory
    The error message is registered = 0 : Cannot launch this VM.
    Shared memory is not enough.

Comment: Restarting the machine fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 4):

From tizen thread https://bugs.tizen.org/jira/browse/TSDK-8,
use these commands to modify system control variables and that worked fine for me.

```
sudo sysctl -w kern.sysv.shmmax=1610612736
sudo sysctl -w kern.sysv.shmall=393216
sudo sysctl -w kern.sysv.shmmin=1
sudo sysctl -w kern.sysv.shmmni=32
sudo sysctl -w kern.sysv.shmseg=8
sudo sysctl -w kern.maxprocperuid=512
sudo sysctl -w kern.maxproc=2048
```

Comment: Could such tweaking result in any implications for an existing OSX configuration on a Macbook ?  I was thinking of how to be able to restore these parameters to a default value if needed ?

Answer (score 1):

Rebooting my MacBook Pro and running the emulator again resolved the problem for me using Tizen 2.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

Try disable bot of the following acceleration options see if it works:

[image]

If the emulator starts then disable them alternatively and see which of the options might be doing this.

Comment: @DimaMalenko Might be a bug, you can get better response here https://www.tizen.org/community/bug-tracker

Comment: @ Dima Malenko I don't have access to bug tracker can you give me access so that I can report further bugs.

Comment: @Altaf Register to tizen.org/ activate email/ set password / use those credentials to login in JIRA.